A message for Ubdating 22.04 Ubuntu and how to upgrate 22.04 to 24.04 for free and other information
I am getting a message for updating Ubuntu and I okayed it twice but no update occurs.Please guide me if such messages are fake?
Can we manually do the upgrade and is it easy and safe to perform the upgrade for any layman? How much time does it take?
Zulfi.

Have you looked at the upgrade instructions (release notes & other documentation provides a link to them), ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades  which has instructions for Server, Desktop, flavor etc. installs.  You should of course read the release notes for any mitigation instructions for specific hardware or packages you have installed as well; as the first link I provided contains only generic instructions (link to release notes is found on page, along with other links too)

This question is similar to: How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

How long an upgrade will take varies on a number of factors, include the speed of your machine, RAM, disk etc, speed of your internet, what type of install you have & what packages you have installed, and more...  A fresh install is far faster, and often a upgrade via re-install can be faster too  but a new install (clean or unclean) will result in more change than a release-upgraded system as your install release sets a number of defaults (new install will have 24.04 defaults; your existing will have 22.04 or whatever release you install with).  Upgrades can take 40-1440 mins...

Find the official instructions on how to update here. You first need to ensure your current system is fully up to date. Then you can proceed to the upgrade to a newer version of the distribution.
Upgrading using the command line is also an option, according to the same procedure as that of a Ubuntu server.
An upgrade from one LTS version to the next LTS, or from one Ubuntu version to the next is officially supported, so is in principle safe. As it is a matter of clicking through dialogs, the process also is easy and new user friendly.
Still, there is a chance that an upgrade does not go well. Before performing an upgrade, and actually before any system maintenance, make sure the backup of your user data is up-to-date.
